# Error while launching gdb version Eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, gdb

Here is an issue I've worked around by simply not using Eclipse for debugging, but it's getting out-of-hand.

I've used Eclipse Helios, Juno and Kepler over the last year and they all display exactly the same problem when I try to debug a local C/C++ application.

When I try to debug, it simply reports the error "Error while launching gdb --version".

gdb is in my path, but to be sure, I change the Debug settings to list the path explicitly. If I do that, I simply get "Error while launching /usr/bin/gdb --version", which is no better.

I'm using Scientific Linux version 6.4 (as required by my customers) and currently, I'm trying to use Eclipse Kepler. Running from the command line, gdb has no problem reporting it's version:

```
# gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6)
[... licensing info]
```

Please, please let me know how to fix this as I have spent weeks working at only a fraction of the rate I would expect because I'm not utilizing an integrated development environment, but using separate tools.

I've seen other similar posts, but they are either

(a) about Windows / MingW - although I've tried their ideas anyway, just in case they work.
(b) don't have any answer provided.

As Scientific Linux is a RedHat derivative, I expect RHEL or CentOS information would be as relevant for me.

Comment: Have you tried a different GDB launcher? i.e. standard if you're using DSF, or DSF if you're using the standard?

Comment: **Is** gdb installed under `/usr/bin/`? Does `/usr/bin/gdb` exist?

Comment: In my experience this was related to system PATH. Try setting minimal path and retry.